# Using Sitecore publishing agent and publishing an item at specific time

Tags: sitecore, scheduled-tasks, sitecore8, web-publishing

In web.config publishing agent Job is running every 2 minutes. For one item I have added publishing restriction. I have added Publishing from date and time .But the item is getting deleted from web database till that time.

Is this the behavior of sitecore?

Also I tried creating a new version of item and added publishing restriction on that. And it was working as expected. i.e item is not deleted from web database and after specified time it is getting published. Is this solution proper?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is how it is supposed to work.

If you specify **Publishable From** and the **Publishable To** dates, item will be allowed in **web** database only between those 2 dates. That means, if you try to publish this item outside that date range, you will in fact unpublish the item. Similarly, if you set only one of those dates or if you clear the **Publishable** check box.

[image: sitecore - item publishing restrictions]

You can specify date ranges for particular item versions as well. In that scenario, Sitecore will only allow in **web** database the most recent version with either empty publishing restrictions or with publishing restrictions matching actual time.

[image: sitecore - item version publishing restrictions]

You can find more information in [Sitecore Content Author's Reference and Cookbook](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/content_author's_cookbook_sc72-us_letter.pdf), in the **Setting up Publishing Restrictions** chapter.

Screenshots and cookbook relate to **Sitecore 7.2**, but it works in the same way in **Sitecore 8**.